# Can not read large JSON data from inputstream

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
```

Hello,

I am using the `httpUrlConnection` to retrieve a json string from a webservice. Then I get the `inputStream` from the connection

```
jsonString = readJSONInputStream(mHttpUrlconnection.getInputStream());
```

I then use the following function to read the inputstream to get the JSON.

```
private String readJSONInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
    log.log(Level.INFO, "readJSONInputStream()");

    Reader reader = null;

    try {
        final int SIZE = 16092;

        char[] buffer = new char[SIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int read = 0;

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), SIZE);
        bytesRead = reader.read(buffer);

        String jsonString = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "bytesRead: " + bytesRead + " [ " + jsonString + " ]");
        /* Success */
        return jsonString;
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "UnsupportedEncodingexception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        /* close resources */
        try {
            reader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, if the json is small say `600 bytes` then everything is ok (so the code above does work for smaller data). But I have some JSON that is about `15000 bytes` in size so I set the maximum size to `16092`.

However, the JSON it only reads about about `6511` and just cuts off.

I don't understand that if the JSON is small there is no problem. But for the larger JSON it just cuts off at the same size each time.

Am I doing anything wrong here. Anything I should check.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Aren't there size restrictions on HTTP GET requests?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: I am using POST not GET i.e.             mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
String readResponse(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Testing your code now. Should you not test for -1 instead of null in the while loop?

Comment: It is working totally fine, I have used the same code many times. Is it causing you a trouble??

Comment: The return is still truncated/cut for me

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your code is broken here:

```
bytesRead = reader.read(buffer);
```

You should have cycle around read. I think you do not read all chars from stream.

Answer (score 1):

You should continue to read from the buffer until bytesRead = -1.

I suspect that the reader is buffering the data and only returning a certain amount of data at a time.

Try looping until bytesRead == -1 with each loop append the read data to your resultant String.